# Value of reputation in real life

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

Sorry for the heavy edit, the community comments made me understand that I asked the wrong question (maybe just in the wrong way).

Some time to think about this made me realize the real question I wanted to ask was slightly different:

**Should I invest my reputation (offer a bounty) for someone else's gain?**

Comment: "How should I see investing my reputation points for my day job?" Don't.

Comment: I believe you should NOT treat reputation as a job reputation. It's fun, like playing football without getting hurt... Not an _"investment"_.

Comment: So, you have a problem at work. You ask on Stack Overflow and get a free solution. And you expect your employer, who pays you to do the actual work, to also put a bounty on your question (or otherwise reward you)? Well, you can always ask them...

Comment: @BoltClock straight and effective. Should have been an answer, not a comment.

Comment: When you will be active enough and gain enough reputation you will be invited to careers.stackoverflow.com - in there the reputation becomes integral part of your CV. [Example of my CV](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/publish/45190) - that's the closest you will get to "value of reputation in real life"

Comment: If anybody gets to this stage, they should click on the down arrow next to their username in the top bar, click "log out", turn their computer off and go outside for a bit.

Comment: @YannisRizos my employer has a problem and asks me to solve it. If he had some reputation points he should spend them to solve the problem faster. Let's make a not so real life example: my boss pays me per work hour. Bounty = problem solved in 1h, I gain 10$, I lose 100 rep. No bounty = problem solved without help, solved in 10h, I gain 100$.

Comment: I'm fighting the urge to post a simple three letter word, consisting of the 23rd, 20th and 6th letters of the alphabet.

Comment: I realize also this question has a personal nature and maybe shouldn't have been asked.

Comment: @Gabber I don't think that's going to work, but it's something you'll need to discuss with your boss. If one of my team members came up with such a proposal, I'd deny it, but I'm not your boss and I have absolutely no idea how your boss will react. All I can say is that I think it's a terrible idea...

Comment: @YannisRizos In the end I think you are right. Maybe the best thing would be my boss investing his rep to help me solve the problem to keep the project going... If he had some points. The problem is that reputation for me is precious, as it represents gratitude... Maybe I should show more gratitude in the first place

Comment: If you die in Stack Overflow *you die in real life*

Comment: Only if you also benefit from it.  I've used my reputation for bounty several times solving difficult problems in order to complete a project I was working on more quickly than if I had worked out the answer myself.

Ostensibly my clients benefitted from my reputation.

However, I also directly benefitted. My clients know I can either figure out the difficult aspects of a project, or have the resources to figure it out. I'm being paid for the work I'm doing.  The more time I save in a given project, the more projects I can handle and generally the more compensation I get.

Comment: Well, maybe not a good questions, but good feedback anyway, thanks! I really appreciated the non angry answers (and replies)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most users answer questions as a hobby as new questions create more curiosity and research. More research means more knowledge. So ultimately the knowledge you have gained by asking or answering questions should matter in your life, not reputation. Knowledge should be your main reward.

Of course, Reputation is a measure of trust. Reputation is money, You can buy good answers with it. But reputation shouldn't matter as much as knowledge when it comes to your life.

So offering a bounty shouldn't be a bad idea if you are rich (high reputation) and if you wanted to ask a question similar to it.

Comment: Thanks for answering without hatred.

Comment: You are most welcome. but why do you say "without hatred"?

Comment: @ahmedtabrez because there were a lot of negativity in the comments above, and your level-headed response was appreciated. +1

Comment: Glad you appreciate.... thankyou

Comment: I could have said "kindly"... but the edit time has expired.

Comment: LOL. That's not at all a problem...

Comment: great answer, knowledge is what we all are here for, reputation is an additional thing.

Answer (score 4):

SO rep should never be taken as a measure of knowledge, experience, ability or self-worth.

For example, I have more rep than [Bjarne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109934), [Randal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22483), and [Guido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/818274) combined but I [cower at their programming prowess](http://images.icanhascheezburger.com/completestore/2008/8/23/iamnotworthy128640025049340924.jpg).

What you can infer for someone with high rep is that he/she has chosen to invest their time in participating in the site and their effort is appreciated by others.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why are you trying to commercialize, Reputation?

I value my reputation points very much. Because that amount shows how much community has believed on me so far.

And I don't think it should be regarded as an asset, or an business deal from which you invest, hoping to gain some profit.

If I offer a bounty on a question, I am giving it to get some good answers not **rep points**.

Comment: Of course I'm not trying to commercialize my reputation. Maybe I'm not so good at speaking English as I thought, I'll try to edit my question to get to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Reputation has no monetary value outside the StackExchange network. Unless you are able to turn bragging value into hard cash.

Inside the value is [explained on this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges).

Comment: `Unless you are able to turn bragging value into hard cash.` Some people can do that http://www.zdnet.com/blog/apple/color-new-social-photo-app-arrives-for-ios/9838. It is actually a requirement if you want to be a CEO.